# How to get the most current data from a Temporal Feature Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-10.4, time

I have created a Temporal Feature Layer on our ArcGIS Server, which records all the locations, along with timestamp & other attributes of moving vehicles.

I used the [TimeSlider Sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/time_sliderwithdynamiclayer.html), to create a custom App which shows this data along with a TimeSlider.

When user presses play, it shows all the locations for a Given Vehicle (in that time extent) on the Map.

Is there a way to configure the timeSlider, or even make a custom query to the REST Endpoint of the FeatureService, to get the most current data/location for each vehicle in that particular time extent, and not all?

(I'm basically trying to get [this kind](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/tracking-analyst/066-symbolizing-only-most-current-events.htm) of behavior in a web app)

Answer (score 1):

The key is in the renderer, specifically the TemporalRenderer.  Use its latestObservationRenderer to show the "latest" for each vehicle.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/temporalrenderer-amd.html